# Out of boundary conditions

Tags: c, types, boundary

How to check out of boundary condition and print a message in C language? For example, let `sizeof(int)`=4 bytes, how to check if user input value is more than `2^31`?

Comment: where user input value is a string? If so, what are you using currently to parse the string. Show the code.

Comment: The prgm is get sum of digits of an integer. The input is taken as integer only, but how to put a check if there's an input value beyond the range?

Comment: You need to test the users input before it is placed in an `int` afterwards you can check for between `2^31-2^32`, but they could have entered a larger number. It also depends on the code you are using to convert from users `char*` to `int` so I repeat, show the code!!!

Comment: @user299520 Are you asking how to check if an `int` is outside of the range of an `int`?

Answer (score -1):

If integer overflow occures then the sum value becomes < 0. Try this code snippet:

```
void checkOverflow()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int digits = 10000000000;       // one bilion
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sum += digits;
        if (sum < 0)
        {
            printf("Integer overflow - %i", sum);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Since when C started having a construct/method called `cout`??? Also, this code won't compile, as you're not returning any int value whereas your function is defined to return an int.

Comment: Signed integer overflow has undefined behavior. You can't check for it after the fact.

Comment: Pardon, I've add the code without compiling it. Corrections added. But in any case you've got the idea.

Comment: Take a look at this answer though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c. Mine is just an example to show what happens on integer overflow.